# How to call a Scala method that has Numeric parameter from Java

Tags: java, scala

I have a Scala method that takes a `Numeric[T]` object:

```
def needNumeric[T](value: T)(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = {
  // do something
}
```

How do I call this method from Java? The best way I've come up with is this:

```
needNumeric(0, scala.math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral$.MODULE$);
```

But the code looks ugly and is not very general. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Try to take hint from `Java` `bytecode` generated from the compiled `Scala` code

Comment: Do you have to call this method directly from Java? Or are you allowed to create some new Scala methods that call this method?

Comment: @Tim Scala helper method works too, but the only way I found there is by creating a `needNumericJava(value: Any)` then pattern matching `value` against the numeric types and calling `needNumeric()`, which also looks very verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java supports polymorphic methods, so how about something like this:

```
object original {
  def needNumeric[T](value: T)(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = {
    // do something
  }
}

object NeedNumeric {
  def needNumeric(value: Int) = original.needNumeric(value)
  def needNumeric(value: Long) = original.needNumeric(value)
  def needNumeric(value: Float) = original.needNumeric(value)
  def needNumeric(value: Double) = original.needNumeric(value)
  def needNumeric(value: BigInt) = original.needNumeric(value)
  ...
}

import NeedNumeric._
```

It is tedious to have to enumerate the types (which is why the Scala uses a type class) but it should be OK for numerical values as there aren't very many numeric types.

---

If this is your own `needNumeric` method then note that the signature can be simplfied to this:

```
def needNumeric[T: Numeric](value: T) = {
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight workaround for the ugliness issue: define Java-convenient access like

```
class Numerics {
    public static final Numeric<Integer> INTEGER = Numeric.IntIsIntegral$.MODULE$;

    public static final Numeric<Double> DOUBLE = Numeric.DoubleIsFractional$.MODULE$;

    ...
}
```

The tradeoff is that it allows calling any method requiring `Numeric`s without modifying it.